# Как добавить hover элементу .checkbox_input::before? Именно бефоре

Tags: css

```
    .checkbox {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

    .checkbox_input{
    position: relative;
}

    .checkbox_input::before {
  content: "";
  background: url('');
  background-color: #423E6B;
  width: 17.5px;
  height: 17.8px;
  border-radius: 2.9px;
  display: block;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  top: -4px;
  left: -19px;
  color: #131129;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}

.checkbox:checked+.checkbox_input::before {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 3;
}

    .checkbox:hover {
  background-color: #6e6794;
  border-color: #c7c7ff;
  z-index: 2;
}

  input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  border: 2px solid #423E6B;
}
.checkbox_input::before:hover{
border-color: #c7c7ff;
z-index: 5;
```

}

```
<label class="label">
<input type="checkbox"  class="checkbox checkbox_input" name="">
<span class="checkbox_input hover_check"></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Сначала нужно писать псевдокласс :hover, а затем псевдоэлемент :before, таким образом:

```
div:hover:before{}
```